# Ubuntu 18.04. only works in recovery mode

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I can only open my Ubuntu 18.04.in recovery mode from advanced settings.
I found out on some forums that I have to switch drivers but then when I went on Adittional drivers I found out that I dont have any drivers. I went on AMD to install driver for my laptop but found out there is no version for Linux. 
What to do next? I can still use it normally from recovery mode, but if I just select Ubuntu the screen freezes, and also one time it showed the message BUG:soft lockup-CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [systemd-udevd:367]. 
I have enough storage and I'm running in dual boot. Everything was fine the last time I was using my laptop... Please help
I have Lenovo IdeaPad S145 with AMD Athlon 300u with radeon vega mobile gfx x 4,that I bought a few months ago...
Thank you!

Comment: The Radeon driver is precompiled into the Linux kernel, so there is no _proprietary_ external driver for your GPU in Ubuntu. Let's go back to basics. When you made your LiveUSB you used to install Ubuntu, did you check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Comment: When you log into Ubuntu normally, do you get as far as your desktop, and then it freezes? In Recovery Mode, if you have to, edit your question with the output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` or `ls -al /home/your_username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @K7AAY I haven't checked that but I downloaded it directly from Ubuntu.com, should I do it now?

Comment: @heynnema It shows the purple color screen like the color of the standard wallpaper and then black screen and thats it...

Comment: Yes. The download process is subject to errors creeping in to the file. Had you used a Torrent to download it, no, because Torrents include checksum verification. If it does verify, move on to https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: No, I just downloaded it directly from the browser....

Comment: But everything was fine for a couple of months...

Comment: Also I cant change my screen brightness, it's on high all the time

Comment: @xiteya From Recovery Mode, you need to show me the answers that I asked in my comment yesterday. That way I can begin to help you.

Comment: @xiteya Let's try this. Boot to the GRUB menu. Hit the "e" key to enter edit mode. Use the arrow keys to locate "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then hit control-x or F10 to continue booting. What happened?